# Select random value for each row

Tags: sql, postgresql, random

I'm trying to select a new random value from a column in another table for each row of a table I'm updating. I'm getting the random value, however I can't get it to change for each row. Any ideas? Here's the code:

```
UPDATE srs1.courseedition
SET ta_id = teacherassistant.ta_id
FROM srs1.teacherassistant
WHERE (SELECT ta_id FROM srs1.teacherassistant ORDER BY RANDOM()
       LIMIT 1) = teacherassistant.ta_id
```

Comment: Actual table definitions, cardinalities and your version of Postgres would make this more insightful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that Postgres is optimizing out the subquery, because it has no dependencies on the outer query.  Have you simply considered using a subquery?

```
UPDATE srs1.courseedition
    SET ta_id = (SELECT ta.ta_id
                 FROM srs1.teacherassistant ta
                 ORDER BY RANDOM()
                 LIMIT 1
                );
```

I don't think this will fix the problem (smart optimizers, alas).  But, if you correlate to the outer query, then it should run each time.  Perhaps:

```
UPDATE srs1.courseedition ce
    SET ta_id = (SELECT ta.ta_id
                 FROM srs1.teacherassistant ta
                 WHERE ce.ta_id IS NULL  -- or something like that
                 ORDER BY RANDOM()
                 LIMIT 1
                );
```

You can replace the `WHERE` clause with something more nonsensical such as `WHERE COALESCE(ca.ta_id, '') IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: I tested both the codes and the first returns the same value for all (as you predicted) but the second just returns null. Am I missing something?

Comment: @EuanHollidge . . . Try `ce.ta_id <> ta.ta_id` or something to correlate the subquery to the outer query.

Comment: The 1st query will most certainly fail like you mentioned and update all rows with the same value. The 2nd query is a loaded footgun: only updates rows with `courseedition.ta_id IS NULL` properly, all other rows are set to NULL, because the correlated subquery returns no row. Either way, probably better not to run a new subquery for every row to begin with. Also depends on the exact definition of "random".

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . I changed the condition to one that should always run.  I agree that this approach may not be the best way assign a random value . . . It is the path the OP was original on.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: But `WHERE COALESCE(ca.ta_id, '') IS NULL` is even worse: would assign NULL to *all* rows, since the correlated subquery never returns anything.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . Lol.  Fixed.

Comment: @Gordon: That's more like it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This following solution should be **faster by order(s) of magnitude** than running a correlated subquery for every row. **N** random sorts over the whole table vs. **1** random sort. The result is just as random, but we get a perfectly even distribution with this method, whereas independent random picks like in [Gordon's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46373532/939860) can (and probably will) assign some rows more often than others. There are different kinds of "random". Actual requirements for "randomness" need to be defined carefully.

Assuming the number of rows in `courseedition` is bigger than in `teacherassistant`.

To update *all* rows in `courseedition`:

```
UPDATE srs1.courseedition c1
SET    ta_id = t.ta_id
FROM  (
   SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY random()) - 1 AS rn  -- random order
        , count(*) OVER () As ct                           -- total count
        , ta_id
   FROM   srs1.teacherassistant           -- smaller table
   ) t
JOIN (
   SELECT row_number() OVER () - 1 AS rn  -- arbitrary order
        , courseedition_id                -- use actual PK of courseedition
   FROM   srs1.courseedition              -- bigger table
   ) c ON c.rn%t.ct = t.rn                -- rownumber of big modulo count of small table
WHERE  c.courseedition_id = c1.courseedition_id;
```

#### Notes

Match the random rownumber of the bigger table modulo the count of the smaller table to the rownumber of the smaller table.

`row_number() - 1` to get a 0-based index. Allows using the modulo operator `%` more elegantly.

Random sort for *one* table is enough. The smaller table is cheaper. The second can have any order (arbitrary is cheaper). The assignment after the join is random either way. Perfect randomness would only be impaired indirectly if there are regular patterns in sort order of the bigger table. In this unlikely case, apply `ORDER BY random()` to the *bigger* table to eliminate any such effect.